# Google apps script cannot get url parameter from page on new Google site

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, url-parameters, google-sites

My current site (Golf League) uses several scripts to allow players to schedule whether they are playing, display various results pages etc. It seems as though the New Google Sites implementation does not allow a parameter to be passed in the page url and get picked up by an embedded Google Web App (published from my script)

This link shows an example https://sites.google.com/site/kitchenergaffers/home/general-gaffers-information/publish/directory-of-results?display=directory

There is my webapp (built from a GAS) that does a doGet(e). The "display" parameter tells this script which page to format and display which it gets by extracting the e.queryString. I use a similar approach for players scheduling their absences. Another url parameter identifies the player who may be changing their availability.

It seems as though this ability is not going to be supported in the New Google Sites, so I am looking for an alternative (and free) web building facility where I can launch GAS web apps and access the page url parameters the same (or similar) way. Wordpress, Wix etc may be candidates, but it is difficult to tell from their introductory info whether it can be done. If someone has already found a site facility and methodology I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Yes, it used to work before whith gadget, but now, it seems that the only solution is to render the web app directly with the 'ugly' url containing a deployemnt id https://script.google.com/macros/s/my-deployment-id/exec?myparam=123

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone finds this in a search, I have found a workaround.
What I had missed is that a script can be the target of a URL and will execute in a browser on its own. It does not need a "hosting" page. So to achieve what I need to do, instead of sending the link with the Google sites page, I can send a link with the script directly and it will happily execute in its own browser environment. In some cases, I may need to add a bit of text to the html returned by the script to replace that which was on the Sites page

So this link (below) achieves what I needed. Be aware that the links displayed by the script, are currently still to the original sites page.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxichdoGrHbImuudkJbuhhD00GpHvVvc-Ph_BTpSI4863pMevVx/exec?display=directory